# PHP preg_match_all() matching too much

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable called `$content` which contains the contents of a [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/wiki:syntax#links) Markdown file.

I am trying to match all the links in which the style is: `[[http://url.com/|title]]`

Here is part of the variable I am trying to match against:

```
[[http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm|Eclipse]], [[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx|Visual Studio]] and [[https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html|IntelliJ Idea]]
```

My current regular expression is: `/\[\[(.*)\|([\w\s]+?)\]\](?=\,|\s)/`
but it matches the entire part I have listed above including the `,` and the `and`.

What I want is each of the links separated out, so the result I'm looking for from `preg_match_all('/regular_expression/', $content, $links);` is:

```
$links[0][0] = [[http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm|Eclipse]]
$links[0][1] = [[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx|Visual Studio]]
$links[0][2] = [[https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html|IntelliJ Idea]]

$links[1][0] = http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm
$links[1][1] = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
$links[1][2] = https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html

$links[2][0] = Eclipse
$links[2][1] = Visual Studio
$links[2][2] = IntelliJ Idea
```

Comment: Change the: `(.*)` (which is too greedy and non-precise) to: `([^|\[\]]*)`.

Comment: Questions or issues with answer?

Comment: Nope, I understand what you changed and I implemented it and it worked great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
$string = '[[http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm|Eclipse]], [[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx|Visual Studio]] and [[https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html|IntelliJ Idea]]';
preg_match_all('/\[{2}(.+?)\|([\w\s]+?)\]{2}/', $string, $links);
print_r($links);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [[http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm|Eclipse]]
            [1] => [[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx|Visual Studio]]
            [2] => [[https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html|IntelliJ Idea]]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm
            [1] => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
            [2] => https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Eclipse
            [1] => Visual Studio
            [2] => IntelliJ Idea
        )

)
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iM4kG3/1

Just need your `*` to be non-greedy `?` and you probably want something before that `|` so make the quantifier a `+` (one or more); can change that back to a `*` if you dont care if there is anything there...